# PHP and MySQL - Get number of specific results from column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for getting how many results there are in results there are in a column:

```
$result = "SELECT name FROM users";

echo $result;
```

How can I display a certain number of a specific string? For example, I want to search for the name "Andrew" in the column "name". There are 20 results for "Andrew". How can I echo out "20"?

Comment: I didn't do the downvoting but, as a heads up, I'm sure the person did it because this is a very "Google-able" question.  Googling "count results in sql" would have returned you the answer, quite possibly even linking to a question already posted on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You would `COUNT` them:

```
$result = "SELECT COUNT(`name`) AS `NameCount` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = 'Andrew'";
```

For all names you could do this:

```
SELECT `name`, count(`name`) AS `NameCount`
FROM `users`
GROUP BY `name`
```

Which would result in something like this:

```
name    |    NameCount
----------------------
Andrew  |           20
Bob     |            6
Carol   |          125
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will use Mysqli, you can use $num_rows. Somelithing like:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

also, you can use mysql count() function like:

```
$result = "SELECT count(*), name FROM users";
```